# Is there any way to add timed text in Android 2.3?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am a beginner in Android. I want to make an audio player with lyrics.

I found a way in API level 16 and above

```
player.addTimedTextSource(getSubtitleFile(R.raw.sub))
```

I want to implement these functionality in below versions too.

Is there any way to implement this?

Comment: Take a look at the android support library to see if that's been implemented

Comment: no , you need to create your own logic for this

Comment: you can easily achieve this thing

Comment: Reading the source code of addTimedTextSource may be helpful :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to follow these step :

1. read the srt file like:

   ```
   InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.selena1);
   int size = is.available();
   byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
   is.read(buffer);
   is.close();
   ```
2. when you open the srt file, you can see the the time in the srt file. You need to retrieve that time and made an array for the start time  & another array for the time delay.
3. When you complete with this start Handler with the start of Player
4. Now from the Array duration you can decide the time interval of the subtitle display which will handle through the Handler class, like:

   ```
   private Handler myHandler = new Handler();
   private Runnable drawRunnable = new Runnable() {

       @Override
       public void run() {
           myHandler.postDelayed(this, delay);     
       }
   };
   ```
5. you need to manage your logic according to this.